# Vintage motorcycle repair--where to find parts?

Tags: motorcycle

I'm thinking about picking up my first motorcycle. I'm looking at older bikes, 60s-80s, primarily Japanese bikes. I'm plenty handy around cars, so the maintenance tasks don't concern me, but I'm wondering if finding replacement parts for these bikes will be very difficult.

Where does one find parts for vintage bikes?

Comment: If you provide some of the manufacturers and years your interested in I have a huge list of resources.  Some are model specific.

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on where you are and the individual make and type of the vehicle. The best bet is to join a local marque-specific owners club, these will usually have all the contacts you need, and many are actively involved in sourcing (and in some cases remanufacturing) rare parts.

The same applies to any older vehicle of course, not just bikes...

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten car parts from [Vintage Parts](http://www.vpartsinc.com/).  Looks like they carry some Harley parts, but no Yamaha, for example.  Almost everything that was ever mass produced turns up on Ebay if you wait long enough, for certain definitions of 'long enough'.

Answer (score 1):

This place has lots of good stuff:  [Garage Company](http://www.garagecompany.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to look into an old British bike, parts availability is really good.  You can literally build a new Norton Commando from all new parts.